# Can wissen mean remember?

Tags: word-usage

In a book I'm reading, the author used the question "Weißt du noch". I'm guessing from the context it means "Do you remember". Is that so? Does the addition of the word "noch" turn "wissen" into "remember"?

Comment: Strictly to meaning, "Do you recall", or "Can you recall" might be more accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context you gave, your translation is perfectly right.

However, there is a subtle difference between *wissen* and *erinnern.* The latter would imply that you can recall the precise memory from your mind including enough detail to replay substantial parts of the topical event. For *wissen,* it suffices to know the event happened (perhaps by remembering some other fact that implies the original event).

This difference has very little relevance in actual language use. It might make a difference in a police interrogation or some other contrived setting.

Example:

> Erinnerst du dich noch an unser erstes Treffen in London? – Do you still remember our first date in London?)

You would be expected to remember the walk along the River Thames, the stroll through Notting Hill bookstores etc.

> Weißt du noch, wie wir uns das erste Mal getroffen haben? – Do you still know when we first met?

You might only remember to have seen some email dating back to the time that mentions the London visit, though you have no memory of it (don’t you tell her *that* …).

Comment: Is this why erinnern appears with the reflexive?  If erinnern means personal memory of an event and wissen means general recollection of an event, then is that why the reflexive is useful?  Apologies, but I'm better at feeling when to use the reflexive than I am at knowing why to use it (though still weak at both).

Comment: @NL7 I can't say whether your hypothesis is correct (the difference stated in my answer is really subtle, so I'm doubtful). Note however that `sich erinnern`-> `to remember`, `erinnern` -> `to remind`. There has been a recent trend of using the irreflexive form with the semantics of the reflexive verb, but it's not yet mainstream (at least that's my impression).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, exactly.

"Remember" doesn't mean anything else than "to still know". I guess we prefer saying "weißt Du noch" (3 syllables) instead of "erinnerst Du Dich" (5 syllables) because it's shorter.

Comment: Both version a very common from my experince. Maybe depending on region and cultural group - but don't have any pattern so far ;)

Comment: @frlan I'd rather think it depends on context. "Weißt du noch, um wieviel Uhr ..." would sound slightly odd with "erinnern", but "Erinnerst du dich noch an den Tag..." would sound absolutely off with "wissen"

Comment: Hmmm...  yeah. True. I was thinking about the typical "Damals" session with grandparents ...

Comment: @Em1 I think it doesn't depend on context, but syntactical usage: `sich *an etwas* erinnern` can't be formulated by `noch wissen` as it can't have a prepositional object. `sich erinnern + subclause` can be formulated by `noch wissen`. And "Erinnerst du dich, um wie viel Uhr …" doesn't sound odd to me at all.

Answer (score 3):

another example:
„I [**still**] KNOW WHAT YOU DID LAST SUMMER“ (dt. „Ich weiß [**noch**], was Du letzten Sommer getan hast“)

The **question** should be "What is the difference between '**to know**' and '**to remember**'?". 
I think 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remember_versus_know_judgements
gives an idea about the difference. And maybe the above-mentioned example helps you to cope with **noch**. I am getting more and more confused, whether **noch** has the power to change the meaning of **wissen**. Maybe **noch** really helps to put some memory back to consciousness. So if you still know sth, you can remember it exactly - which is a different meaning.

Really good question! I hope we are getting a consensus and a good explanation.

Comment: Knowing and remembering are indeed very confusing concepts. However, German is the only language I know that really catches the essence and actually formulates recalling as "still knowing".

Answer (score 3):

I would only add to the current answers the probable *answers* to the question  "Weißt du noch?":

*Ich weiß nicht mehr.* is what what Germans would say if they *don't (can't) remember (anymore)*.

*Ja, weiß ich.* means in this context *Yey, I (do) remember.*

It doesn't happen very often that a German would like to be *genau* with the subtlety of the difference between *wissen* and *erinnern*, mainly because *errinern* is much more difficult to say quickly, and to my knowledge, efficiency is the rule of thumb for speaking as it is for many other aspects of being a German :)